# How to create a type safe generic array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I want to create a generic array in java maintaining the type safety usually offered by Java.

I am using this code :

```
class Stack<T> { 

private T[] array = null;
public Stack(Class<T> tClass, int size) {
   maximumSize = size;
   // type unsafe
   //array = (T[])new Object[maximumSize];

   this.array = (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(tClass,maximumSize);
}
```

is this code type safe? ans if so, why? why if it is type safe I need a cast?

Comment: In the above code `(T[])` simply casts to `Object[]`, since the type T is unknown at compile time.  Therefore `array` must be of type `Object[]` (or simply `Object`).  If you *return* a value typed `T[]` then, at the point of call, the compiler will throw in a hidden cast to the appropriate type, when the method's return value is assigned or used.

Comment: Can you update your code so it compiles? Where does `T` come from? How is `array` declared? For example is this a static method you have mind (such that is just a wrapper around `Array#newInstance`) or is `array` a field and `T` is a type parameter to a class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`Array.newInstance(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29) method has a return type of `Object`. As such, you cannot directly assign it to anything other than `Object`. You therefore need a cast.

The method delegates to a `native` method which

> Creates a new array with the specified component type and length

Therefore it is creating an array of type `T`.

The type safety, assuming `array` is declared as

```
T[] array;
```

, is guaranteed by the `Class<T>` parameter and the cast using the same type variable.

You should add the

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

with a comment explaining the above reason in your source code. Always comment why a cast whose warning you are suppressing is safe.

Comment: why I am getting an unchecked warning?

Comment: You are making an *unchecked cast* so you get a warning for using it.

Comment: @GiuseppePes Because the compiler can't guarantee it. The method specification should.

Comment: Note that the compiler could have guaranteed it if there was a `newInstance` specifically dedicated to reference-typed arrays. `static <T> T[] newInstance(Class<T> c, int size)`

Comment: So, I cannot get type safety guarantee by the compiler because I am using the generic. Nevertheless, the type safety is guarantee at run time by parameter passed in the constructor?

Comment: Note that doing this will throw an exception for primitive types. For example `int.class` is a `Class<Integer>` therefore casting an `int[]` into an `Integer[]`. There's not a way to represent the primitives generically. That's why it could be unsafe.

Comment: @GiuseppePes Guaranteed for everything except Radiodef's comment above mine. You wouldn't typically be using primitives with generics though.

Comment: @Radiodef brought up a really good point. If I want to create a utterly generic container able to contain any type including primitive types I have to take into account this problem . Wouldn't be better to use a  `T[] array = (T[])Object[size];`

Comment: @GiuseppePes Basically you can't include primitives if you want to do this generically in the way you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

It's not type safe because of the primitive Class objects. For example I can create a new Stack in the following manner:

```
new Stack<Boolean>(boolean.class, 10);
```

Which is OK with the compiler but throws an exception because [`boolean.class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#TYPE) is a `Class<Boolean>` and `boolean[]` cannot be cast to `Boolean[]`.

The alternative you show commented out:

```
array = (T[])new Object[size];
```

*Is* actually somewhat type safe but for a different reason: it is due to erasure. You cannot, for example, cast a `new Object[size]` to a `Number[]`, but the cast never happens on the array. It happens some time later, like when you return an element of the array from a method (in which case the element is casted). If you tried to do something like return the array to outside the object it will throw an exception.

Usually the solution is not to generically type the array. Instead, do something like this:

```
class Stack<E> {
    Object[] array = new Object[10];
    int top;

    void push(E elem) {
        if(top == array.length)
            array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length * 2);

        array[top++] = elem;
    }

    E pop() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E elem = (E)array[--top]; // type safe cast

        array[top] = null;

        return elem;
    }
}
```

The above cast is type safe because you can only push an `E` in to the array. Both the JDK Stack (which extends Vector) and ArrayList work this way.

If you want to use `newInstance`, you would have to reject primitives as there is no way to represent them generically:

```
Stack(Class<T> tClass, int size) {
    if(tClass.isPrimitive())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Nice detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since `Array.newInstance` returns an `Object` it needs a cast. The compiler will always give warning in such cases. This is the limitation of generics.

Answer (score 0):

As we know that generics are checked at the compile time so, my friend 
java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(tClass,size); returns you the object and you are type casting it, and if array is not of type T[] then there can be compile time error