# Is it a good practice to cast the generic array during initialization?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

For example,
I'm trying to initialize a generic array of class `Node<E>`.

```
Node<Integer>[] nodes =(Node<Integer>[])new Node[10];
```

Is this a good practice? If not, what is a better way of doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java - Arrays and Generics do have some caveats in Java. I don't think that there is a best practice for it (but check the answers) - I would use a `List` like `ArrayList`, you can even [make a List of a fixed size - backed by an array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5207205/664577).

Answer (score 0):

This is the quick and dirty way to do it. There are other methods that are more "safe" so to speak. You can find them in a previously answered question here: [How to create a type safe generic array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467332/how-to-create-a-type-safe-generic-array-in-java)